# Fingerprint sensor Asus Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, 22.04, fingerprint-reader

> sudo lsusb

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0329 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB3.0 Card Reader

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 3277:0021 Sonix Technology Co., Ltd. USB2.0 FHD UVC WebCam

**Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1c7a:0587 LighTuning Technology Inc. ETU905A88-E**

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0033 Intel Corp.

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

```
fprint-enroll username
```

> Impossible to enroll:
> GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices
> available

I have tried to compile libfprint but of no use. Any ideas has to how to make it for the version Egistec Sensor version ***0587***

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: fingerprint sensors in Ubuntu mostly either "work" or "don't work". This one doesn't look supported.